# django rest framework serializer.data throws error about attribute in manytomany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I have the following models:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):

    class Category(models.TextChoices):
        PIZZA = "pizza"
        SIDE = "side"
        OTHER = "other"
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Category.choices, default=Category.OTHER)

class Order(models.Model):

    class OrderStatus(models.TextChoices):
        NEW = "new"
        READY = "ready"
        DELIVERED = "delivered"

    customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(MenuItem, through='OrderItem')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=OrderStatus.choices, default=OrderStatus.NEW)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

And the following serializers:

```
class MenuItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = serializers.FloatField(default=0.0)
    category = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return MenuItem.objects.create(**validated_data)

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    menu_item_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=MenuItem.objects.all(), source='menu_item', read_only=False)
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    customer = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order_items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for order_item_data in order_items_data:
            quantity = order_item_data.pop('quantity')
            menu_item = order_item_data.pop('menu_item')
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, quantity=quantity, menu_item=menu_item)
        return order
```

And then in views:

```
@csrf_exempt
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        print(serializer.errors)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

An example request looks like:

```
echo -n '{"customer": "John Doe", "items": [{"menu_item_id": 1, "quantity": 2}, {"menu_item_id": 2, "quantity": 1}]}' | http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/order
```

When serializer.data is called an error is thrown:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
> field `menu_item_id` on serializer `OrderItemSerializer`. The
> serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any
> attribute or key on the `MenuItem` instance. Original exception text
> was: 'MenuItem' object has no attribute 'menu_item'.

So its gone through the serializer.save() but errors on serializer.data. Can't work out why it can't get a value `menu_item_id` as it should be related to the `id` on `MenuItem` with the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're accidentally applying the `OrderItemSerializer` to the wrong model. In `OrderSerializer` the `items` field is defined as an `OrderItemSerializer`, but the `items` field in the model refers to the `MenuItem` model. The `OrderItem` model is only the through-model of the M2M relationship here.

Here are the updated models and serializers that you need.

models.py

```py
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="order_items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Notice that I added `related_name="order_items"` to the FK field that relates it to the `Order` model, so that we can reference this data model easily from the `OrderSerializer`.

serializers.py

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    customer = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        order_items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for order_item_data in order_items_data:
            quantity = order_item_data.pop('quantity')
            menu_item = order_item_data.pop('menu_item')
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, quantity=quantity, menu_item=menu_item)
        return order
```

I changed the name of the field referencing `OrderItemSerializer` to `order_items` so that the serializer is working with `OrderItem` objects now (using the related_name I just configured). The serializer now expects to receive an `order_items` field in the POST body, so make sure to reformat your requests. And in the first line of the `create` method I made sure we're popping `order_items` as well, instead of `items`.

**EDIT**

If you want to take just the ID of the `MenuItem` in the request body, but have the response include all the `MenuItem` data, you can do this with a `serializer.Field`. I'll set it up so that the serializer can accept input data in a different format than it outputs.

serializers.py

```py
class MenuItemField(serializers.Field):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return MenuItem.objects.filter(id=data).first()

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return MenuItemSerializer(value).data

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    menu_item = MenuItemField()
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)
```

`to_internal_value` uses the data provided (the object's ID) to find the `MenuItem` object when the serializer is being used to save data. But when the serializer is being used to show data, the `to_representation` method is called, which uses the `MenuItemSerializer` to show all the object's data.

Notice that I replaced the `menu_item_id` line of `OrderItemSerializer` with `menu_item`, which uses the new `MenuItemField` I defined. This means that your request body should use `menu_item` instead of `menu_item_id`.

Comment: I don't understand why though?
`items` in the Order model doesn't seem to get assigned anything?
For `order` to use the `related_name="order_items"` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Also I was wondering how I could return the full `MenuItem` in a response instead of the `menu_item_id`s.  Would you suggest doing that in the serializer or in the view?

Comment: What related_name does on the FK relationship is give the other model a way to reference the model where the FK was declared (it is created implicitly by Django as `<model_name>_set>`, so related_name actually just changes the name). In this case, we can access the OrderItems related to the Order through that attribute, even though the FK is declared on the OrderItems model. We don't need to assign anything to `items` because we're updating the M2M using the "through" model

Comment: M2M relationships always use a "through" table, but Django usually hides it so it's not apparent that it's there. But any time you add objects to a M2M relationships, you're actually updating the "through" table.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include how to return the MenuItem in the response